# How to get urls of images from your ftp folder using php

Tags: php, html, image, ftp

I wanted to get URLs of images that are in my upload directory of my ftp server and save them into array using PHP script. After I do that I want to show those images as thumbnails. This is what I was trying

```
<?php 

$conn = ftp_connect("ftp.something.com") or die("Could not connect");
ftp_login($conn,"user","pass");

$images = array(ftp_nlist($conn,"upload"));
echo '$images';

for($i=0;$i<20;$i++) {
    echo"<img src='$images[$i]'>";
}
ftp_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Are those images publicly accessible via a web server?

Comment: Are the images on the same server than the HTTP one ?

Comment: Also, double check your filepath. If the ftp login you've provided doesn't dump you in the directory contaning the "upload" directory, then be sure to set the "upload" directory accordingly. But (without testing it personally) it looks like this code should work...
One suggestion- why not change your for loop to:

for($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ftp_nlist`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php) already returns an array, so if you put that in an array, you get a multidimensional array with only one element at index 0.

You should just use:

```
$images = ftp_nlist($conn,"upload");
```

And then to check its contents:

```
var_dump($images);
```

Also note that to use your list in html, you would need to add the server address (if it is not on the same server) and path:

```
echo"<img src='http://www.some_server.com/upload/{$images[$i]}'>";
```